Как преобразовать сообщение от сервера в словарь в этом случае?
На запрос от сервера приходит следующее сообщение
"{\"msgTm\": \"2024-07-01T14:36:38.109944Z\", \"message\": \"Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png\"}"

Я пробую преобразовать эту строку в словарь
res = response.json()

Но в результате получаю строку вида:
{"msgTm": "2024-07-01T14:42:53.114348Z", "message": "Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png"}

Возвращается именно тип объекта строка, а не словарь.
При этом если пробую сделать преобразование отдельно строки в словарь то все получается:
import json

response = '{\"msgTm\": \"2024-07-01T14:36:38.109944Z\", \"message\": \"Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png\"}'
res = json.loads(response)

print(res)
print(type(res))

{'msgTm': '2024-07-01T14:36:38.109944Z', 'message': 'Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png'}
<class 'dict'>

А так не получается:
    if response.status_code == 200:
        access_token = "токен"
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'}
        files = {
            'structuredDocument': (file_name, file_io_obj),
        }
        response = requests.post('https://test.ru', headers=headers, files=files, verify=False)
        return response.json()


А вариант починить сломанный сервер по каким-то причинам не рассматривается?

Это не мой сервер. Преобразование в словарь не получается только в том случае когда на сервер отправляются неверные данные и он возвращает сообщение об ошибке в формате json (по крайней мере на него похожем), все остальные запросы с тем же кодом работают успешно и ответ преобразуется в словарь.

Ну значит делайте json.loads когда response.json() выдаёт строку

Спасибо, действительно получилось, мне казалось так пробовал тоже и не сработало, а сейчас перепроверил и реально помогло)
{"msgTm": "2024-07-01T15:15:12.160954Z", "message": "Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png"}
<class 'str'>
{'msgTm': '2024-07-01T15:15:12.160954Z', 'message': 'Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png'}
<class 'dict'>

(но всё равно самым предпочтительным способом решения проблемы будет выписывание живительных люлей разработчику сервера)

Да, я напишу им об этой проблеме, спасибо еще раз)

Спасибо @andreymal, решением стало повторное преобразование в словарь:
res = response.json()
if type(res) == str:
    res = json.loads(res)


Догматичнее делать такую проверку через is: if type(res) is str:

ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ
Не используйте данное решение в 'постоянном' коде: оно подходит для того что бы преобразовать единичные значения (например быстро преобразовать значения где-то в сфере DS, или для отладки). Данное решение имеет ряд проблем по безопасности и не только. Тут оно было приведено больше как пример.
Предложу чуток другое решение. Вы можете просто использовать функцию eval из стандартной библиотеки. Вы просто передаете строку в функцию и она преобразует строку в словарь. Эта функция просто возвращает значение исполненного кода. В данном случае - строки со словарем. Пример:
st = "{\"msgTm\": \"2024-07-01T14:36:38.109944Z\", \"message\": \"Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png\"}"

st2dict_res = eval(st)

print(st2dict_res)
print(type(st2dict_res))

Output:
{'msgTm': '2024-07-01T14:36:38.109944Z', 'message': 'Wrong file extension: .xlsx. Available values: .pdf .jpg, .jpeg, .png'}
<class 'dict'>


"Eval is evil" (c)

Это не только опасно, но и сломается на банальных true/false/null например

Согласен с вами, однако это пример решение из разряда "взял и работает" и его демонстрация, по моему мнению, в целом это не плохо - есть ряд задач где такое решение будет вполне хорошим (например - вам надо быстро преобразовать легенький JSON для того что бы что-то с ним сделать, но это больше про DS всяческий скорее). Однако я согласен что это плохое решение по ряду причин и в продакшене его использовать нельзя. Допишу комментарий к решению об этом.
